# push name and amount to javascript object

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to create an app for a site and users can send money to people on this site. Kinda like twitch. So i wanna create a toplist but i am new to using objects so i'm having some trouble and to explain my problem in a more easy way i added comments in my code

```
var myvar = [];

cb.onTip(function(tip){
  // If username already exists in myvar then i want to just increase the amount for this user else if username does not exist i want to push up the name and amount to myvar
  myvar.push({name: tip.from_user, amount: tip.amount});
}); 

function sendtoplist(user) {
  var msg;
  for(var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    // Here i am trying to create a toplist but i want to sort it by the amount. How can i do this?
    msg += myvar.name + ' ' + myvar.amount+'\n';
  }

  // For some reason this sendNotice returns undefined (probably because i have no idea how to work with objects)
  cb.sendNotice(msg, '', '#000000', '#FFFFFF', 'bold');
  cb.setTimeout(sendtoplist, 30000);
}
cb.setTimeout(sendtoplist, 30000);
```

Comment: Can you please clarify your problem by explaining more precisely what you expect your code to do, and what it currently does not do? Try to post code that others can replicate directly, and run it without needing extra context (in your case there seems to be an object "CB" that is not explained). Also explain the exact problem more precisely in the question text. In your case there seem to be multiple problems: sorting the array, a function that returns undefined, and checking if a user already exists.

Comment: This "cb" part is because the site i am writing the app for uses and API so i need to use cb.onTip(function(){}) to check whenever a user sends money. But i am expecting my code to add username and tip amount to myvar array. And whenever a user send tokens the amount for that user will be increased by (current amount + new amount) and then i want to make a toplist and order it so the member who sent the most tokens will be first on the toplist. The problem i have is that it returns "undefined" in the chat. I hope that answers all your questions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know which specific function is not working?
If so, which error does it show to you?

to your first function:

```
//myvar should be already as an array, imported from a database for example
cb.onTip(function(tip){
// If username already exists in myvar then i want to just increase the amount for this user else if username does not exist i want to push up the name and amount to myvar
var personName = {};
personName.name = tip.from_user;
personName.amount = tip.amount;
var userExist = false;
    for (let i=0; i < myvar.length; i++) {
        if (myvar[i].name == personName.name){
            myvar[i].amount += personName.amount;
            userExist = true;
            break;
        }
    }
if (!userExist) {
    myvar.push(personName);
}

});
```

Is it clear for you? if not let me know.

To your 2nd function, learn some AngularJS basics, it is pretty easy, there you can use a filter and exactly the filter you need which is called ("orderBy")

**Note**:
I really recommend you to learn a framework, instead of using plain JS. If you dont want to learn that much, just learn AngularJS, it must be easy to learn. But if you think you would like to learn some modern framework, the learn Angular (working with typescript is needed)

Comment: Thank you for help. This is a great example. Unfortunately my sendtoplist function still returns undefined. But anyway, the site i am making this for uses an API and i dont think i can write angularjs code there. But this code was still really helpful. I guess i just dont output the message correctly

Comment: @cbbotdev glad to help :) btw I am using AngularJS and Angular on a software that uses many APIs :)